# Spring date changed in client side JSON, the hour is different

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datetime, timestamp

I have an entity that has a date field:

```
import java.util.Date;
...

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ora_programare")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date oraProgramare;
```

In my rest controller, I print the value of this field right before the end of the function that handles my entry point and I can see that the value for the date field is

> oraProgramare=2023-08-01 08:30:00.0

But in POSTMAN I receive a different date:

> "oraProgramare": "2023-08-01T05:00:00.000+00:00"

All dates are changed by 3 hours and 30 minutes, why?

**UPDATE**: I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55380919/problem-with-timezone-in-json-response-from-spring), if I annotate the field with

> @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss",timezone="Europe/Bucharest")

then the hour is correct but I don't understand, my default time zone is "Europe/Bucharest", why is Spring allocating the wrong timezone?
I checked my default timezone using:

```
System.out.println("ZoneId.systemDefault() "+ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

But is complicated to annotate all the datetime fields, I will try to change the type from Date to LocalDateTime

Answer (score 0):

Changing the type of the field from Date to LocalDateTime solved the problem, I'm not sure what was the problem with the type Date, it seems to default to the wrong default timezone.